# Precompiled dex library

Tags: android, dex

My Android project contains a plenty of Java libraries that are compiled to dex each time I launch my application. The libraries do not change. Is there any way to precompile those libraries to dex? It make useless work each time compiling the same libraries to dex while making apk.

Comment: Relevant: [Issue 11604: dx should be able to merge multiple dex files](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11604).

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar problem and have found a solution, you have to use (undocumented) `--incremental` switch with dex too. Refer to [this solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088375/compiling-android-project-from-command-line-is-slow) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the only current workaround: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html