# How to skip libraries (and resources) in the Android build?

Tags: android, ant, build, android-build

I'm using Netbeans and the build of my Android project takes ages.

According to the log, most of the time is spent on library processing. With lines like "input" and "pre-dexing" for every library, followed by a series of "Merged dex A (...) with dex B (...)".
And then I get a series of "Processing image to cache.." for every image in the drawable folders.

The whole process takes around 2 and a half minutes. Which is too much when most of the time you're just changing classes and running again to debug.

How can we skip these libraries and resources processing steps when they're not needed?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans simply delegates to Android SDK. Make sure you use up-to-date version of SDK tools - there were some improvements in that area. It means this is basically duplicate of [Compiling Android project from command line is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088375/compiling-android-project-from-command-line-is-slow)